# Как в joomla добавить два одинаковых плагина с разными настройками

Tags: joomla, php

Использую `Simple Image Gallery`. На сайте надо, чтобы галерея отображалась по-разному. в одном случае надо, чтобы была только одна картинка, при нажатии на которую открывалась галерея, а во втором случае надо чтобы на странице отображались все картинки (например как фотоальбом Вконтакте).

В `Simple Image Gallery` в настройках можно сделать либо так либо так, и выводить в статье используя тег `{gallery}`. Я так понимаю, что можно добавить два одинаковых плагина с разными настройками, но не знаю как это сделать и чтобы теги были разные для каждого варианта.

Comment: Там же по ходу плагин можно скопировать.

Answer (score 0):

Надо продублировать `Simple Image Gallery`, затем выставить в каждом свои настройки и вставить в нужные позиции.